# Unable to integrate CartoDB into Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, carto

This is my first day with CartoDB, trying to integrate our visualization into our existing Leaflet implementation, and having issues. In short: no visualization.

Below is a sample of the problem followed by the code involved. I have a createVis test that works fine, followed by a createLayer test that's not working. The layer seems to add correctly but the tiles don't display.

I've tried:

- With and without lower layers
- Adding the layer in the chain and
  explicitly with "layer.addTo(map)"
- Explicitly making it visible with
  "layer.show()"

No luck so far, and running out of ideas.

http://www.zonability.com/carto.html

```
        var url = 'http://zonability.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/e711de5e-8f77-11e4-a96a-0e0c41326911/viz.json';

        // CreateVis
        cartodb.createVis('map1',url);

        // Integrate into existing Leaflet map
        var map = new L.Map('map2',{
            center: [30.242713340145,-97.770476601062],
            zoom: 9
        });
        map.on('layeradd',function(layer){ console.log('Layer added'); });
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/zonability.glj45k32/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/zonability.gljpogdp/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
        cartodb.createLayer(map,url).on('done',function(layer){
            layer.addTo(map);
            console.log('Done');
        }).on('error',function(err){
            console.log('Error: '+err);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a conflict in the resources you're adding:

> script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js">
>   script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js">

CartoDB.js includes leaflet, so you need to delete Leaflet.js to avoid conflicts.

[image: Working!]